# JSON truncated when compressing HTTP responses

Tags: c#, json, compression, deflate, httplistener

When I apply gzip or deflate compression to my HTTP responses, I seem to be losing the last bracket in my JSON structures. For example:

Result **without** compression:

```
{"alist":{"P_1":0,"P_2":0,"P_3":0}}
```

Result **with** compression as received by the browser:

```
{"alist":{"P_1":0,"P_2":0,"P_3":0}
```

When writing the response **without compression** I am doing the following:

```
byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(responseContent);

context.Response.ContentLength64 = buffer.Length;
context.Response.ContentType = ContentTypeJson;

Stream outputStream = context.Response.OutputStream;
outputStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
outputStream.Close();
```

Alternatively, when the caller provides an Accept-Encoding request header, I try and write the response **with compression** as follows;

```
byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(responseContent);
byte[] compressedBuffer;

using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (Stream compressionStream = new DeflateStream(memoryStream, CompressionMode.Compress, false))
    {
        compressionStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

        compressedBuffer = memoryStream.ToArray();

        compressionStream.Close();
    }

    memoryStream.Close();
}

context.Response.ContentLength64 = compressedBuffer.Length;
context.Response.ContentType = ContentTypeJson;

Stream outputStream = context.Response.OutputStream;
outputStream.Write(compressedBuffer, 0, compressedBuffer.Length);
outputStream.Close();
```

If it helps, I am using an System.Net.HttpListener which is why I have to do this myself. Does anyone have any idea why this truncation may be occuring?

Comment: Try flushing `compressionStream` before you read the array from underlying memoryStream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DeflateStream` doesn't write to its output stream everything immediately after you write into it, but you can be sure it has done so *after* you close it. So the following will work:

```
compressionStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

compressionStream.Close();

compressedBuffer = memoryStream.ToArray();
```

Comment: Order is everything... You were right, that appears to have resolved the issue. Thank you.